# Java-JDBC Need code to throw exception while DB is not responding

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

How to throw an timeout exception when DB is not responding?

I am fetching row from DB2, sometimes it's taking too long to connect to the database.

I want to throw an exception if connection takes more than 1 min. I am using prepared statement in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set set the timeout on the `Drivermanager` using `setLoginTimeout` method:

```
 DriverManger.setLoginTimeout(1000);
 Connection c = DriverManger.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

If the connection cannot open within the specified time in milliseconds then the `getConnecton` call should times out.

Comment: Hi,
How to add the above code here:
DBConnection dbconn = new DBConnection(configuration.getProperties()
    .getProperty("database.name"), configuration.getProperties()
    .getProperty("database.userName"), dbPwd);
  boolean isConnected = dbconn.connect();
  logger.debug("Connection established = " + isConnected);
  if (isConnected)
   connection = dbconn.getConnection();

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `java.util.Timer` class and set the timer for 1min then start pooling.
If you get the connect in time, then cancel the timer or else show the message to the user.

Below is the code sample.

```
    public class TimerSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

                //1- Taking an instance of Timer class.
                Timer timer = new Timer("Printer");

                //2- Taking an instance of class contains your repeated method.
                MyTask t = new MyTask();
                //TimerTask is a class implements Runnable interface so
                //You have to override run method with your certain code black

                //Second Parameter is the specified the Starting Time for your timer in
                //MilliSeconds or Date

                //Third Parameter is the specified the Period between consecutive
                //calling for the method.

                timer.schedule(t, 0, 2000);
            }
        }

class MyTask extends TimerTask {
    //times member represent calling times.
    private int times = 0;


    public void run() {
        times++;
        if (times <= 5) {
            System.out.println("I'm alive...");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Timer stops now...");

            //Stop Timer.
            this.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```